# Appium [MAC] [iOS] Bad pp error

Tags: testing, automated-tests, appium-ios, appium-android

I have an error when trying to launch iOS app by desktop Appium server, i managed to run the test on android device successfully, but failed to do the same for the iOS.

The error is:
>

> Bad app: >/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/app>ium-ios-driver/build/SafariLauncher/SafariLauncher.app. App paths need to be >absolute, or relative to the appium server install dir, or a URL to compressed >file, or a special app name.

My code is:

```
// Set desired capabilities.
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "iOS");
// REAL DEVICE
//capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "iPhone 6s");
capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "Testing iPhone6s");
capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "11.0.1");
capabilities.setCapability("browserName", "Safari");
capabilities.setCapability("orientation", "PORTRAIT");
capabilities.setCapability("udid", "XXXX");
String apkpath="/Users/testing/Desktop/Mohandisi.ipa";
// capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP, apkpath);
File app=new File(apkpath);
capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP, app.getAbsolutePath());
// Open the app.
driver = new IOSDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

I don't know why appium days that the application is bad although i added the full path!

[iOS Settings in Appium Server Screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bqDZf.png)

[image]

Comment: Hi, can you provide the Appium, xcode, ios versions ?

Comment: Appium Version 1.5.3 (Ara), 

Xcode Version: Version 9.2 (9C40b). 

I used Android studio to run the test on real device.

Comment: iPhone 6s plus, OS: 11.0.1

Comment: Use latest stable Appium 1.7.x  dmg:    https://github.com/appium/appium-desktop/releases/tag/v1.3.2 .     Ref: https://github.com/appium/appium/releases .  Follow the instruction.  You are using Appium 1.5.3 and this doesn't support the iOS 11.x

Comment: @arulchristopher
Thank you, I downloaded the 1.7.2 package, unzipped it, but didn't know how to run it! :(

Comment: @arulchristopher
I downloaded node and used rpm to install appium using nom install - g appium, it download successfully, but i faced another problem, i failed to start the appium server, terminal says: command not found. The problem was that the user has no permission on the node or appium folders, i have two users on my MAC and the two user raised the same issue :(

Comment: https://github.com/appium/appium-desktop/releases/tag/v1.3.2   download this desktop app and try

Comment: This will help you 100% https://github.com/saikrishna321/VodQa_MobileAutomationWorkShop/wiki/Appium-Mac-Installation

Comment: Thank you, I installed appium successfully as per the instructions, but when i tried to check the appium version : 
`appium --version`  -> then: `-bash: appium: command not found` !

Comment: https://ibb.co/eJdSNn

Comment: try stable version npm install -g appium

Comment: I tried it but still find the same issue, I think its a path problem.

Comment: `$ /Users/testing/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/appium/lib/appium.js`
The response is:
`-bash: /Users/testing/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/appium/lib/appium.js: Permission denied`

Comment: `sudo /Users/testing/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/appium/lib/appium.js` **BUT** `command not found` !

Comment: /usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/build/lib/main.js

Comment: Thank you, It works, appium started: `/Users/testing/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/appium/build/lib/main.js`

**BUT** i'm wondering about how to open the inspector to record a test.

Comment: Launch the app https://github.com/appium/appium-desktop/releases/tag/v1.4.0  and start the server then inspect element